# Getting WA despite writing correct code with the correct output

Tags: java

This is the basic codechef question: Pooja would like to withdraw `X $US` from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if `X` is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal, the bank charges `0.50 $US`. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.
''

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String args[]){
 Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
 double withdraw = s.nextDouble();      double balance = s.nextDouble();
 if((withdraw%5==0) && balance>=(withdraw+0.50))
 System.out.println("Balance: "+(balance-withdraw-0.50));
 else
 System.out.println("Balance: "+balance);
}
}
```

It's giving the correct output still I'm getting a wrong answer

Comment: Can you post the expected input and output? You may have missed details, such as there being more than 1 test-case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check if withdraw > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Beware modulus, floating-point, and comparing floating-point numbers with "=". It is safer to convert the inputs to long (by multiplying by 100 and using Cents instead of $s). That can avoid some nasty rounding errors with `>= 0.50`, which would now always be exact and look like `>= 50`. When producing output, you would have to convert to dollars again:

```
  static long dollarsToCents(double dollars) { return (long)(dollars*100); }
  
  static String centsAsDollars(long cents) { return "" + (cents/100) + "." + (cents%100); }
```

It is unlikely that the problem is due to this, but look at the following example:

```
    double d = 5_000_000_000_000_000.0; // 5 * 10^15
    double e = 0.5;
    double f = d + e;
    System.out.println("" + d + " + " + e + " = " + f);
    System.out.println("both are equal?: " + (d == f));    // true


    long a = dollarsToCents(d);
    long b = dollarsToCents(e);
    long c = a + b;
    System.out.println("" + a + " + " + b + " = " + c);
    System.out.println("both are equal?: " + (a == c));    // false
```

For increased safety (and if you ever have to handle money in a program), use `BigDecimal`. However, those are much slower than fixed-size integers such as `long`.